# Why does Axios get call return a 404 error with basic setup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I'm trying to set up a React project and want to get a basic get call working. The url I'm using is `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` just for testing and to see if everything is working well. However, I get a 404 error back. The call I make is

```js
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
```

When I try this call with the Fetch API, I get the correct response but with Axios, I get back this error `{status: 404, config: {…}, data: undefined}`. I've been trying to fix this for days and nothing has worked. Is there some type of obvious setup I may have missed?

I followed this tutorial for the most part: https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-how-to-make-http-requests-in-react-part-3-daa6b31b66be

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you check in console  or in networks tab what is the URL being called?

Comment: I am just wondering if in base/global config the base url is already applied

Comment: @Aditya Just checked, the url being called is the right one. I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Comment: Can you print the complete request headers? The source and not the parsed

Comment: according to tags you are using axios-mock-adapter, don't you? if you do than also share how you configure mock adapter itself. by default it returns 404 for all requests except those are mocked explicitly.

Comment: @skyboyer I haven't explicitly configured the mock adaptor. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: how do you use axios-mock-adapter then?

Comment: I guess I don't use it then? I have the npm package and I thought it was needed for axios to function but I don't explicitly use it.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem, as pointed out by @skyboyer the problem is likely to be due to having turned on the `axios-mock-adapter`. If this is the case, you can confirm by looking to your actual network requests in the browser console that `axios` is not doing any request at all (no request to the desired url appears in the list). Check in your code where is a line like this:

```
const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
```

comment it (and related), and hopefully your problem will be solved.

It is also possible to create a mock adapter instance based on empty axios instance (i.e. empty base url). Something like this:

```
const mock = new MockAdapter(axios.create());
```

In this way you won't have to change your test environment each time you want to run test.